# update column in mysql database when user logs in

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to login user and I want to update the value in column loggedin to yes in mysql database. I tried to update it before sending header but it doesn't get updated. Where should I put the code to update the column?

```
if (isset($_POST['login']))
    {
    $username = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']));
    $password = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']));
    $md5password = md5($password);

    // check user and password match to the database

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$md5password'");

    // check how much rows return

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
        {

        // login the user
        // get the id of the user

        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        // start the session and store user id in the session

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $fetch['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $fetch['username'];
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE user SET loggedin = 'yes' WHERE userid = 1;");
        header("Location: message.php");
        }
      else
        {

        // show error message

        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid username Or password.</div>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not matter where you place such a command. It has to be executed, that's all.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that there is no `UPDATE` operation anywhere in this code...

Comment: UPDATE `user` SET `loggedin` = 'yes' WHERE `user`.`id` = 1; im using this but it wont update

Comment: `session_start()` should be your first line of code after opening PHP.

Comment: Why are you updating `userid = 1` instead of the the actual user ID of the user who logged in?

Comment: @Tom That's not necessary, it just has to be before any output or use of `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not updating the correct `userid`. You're updating `userid = 1` instead of the ID belonging to the user who logged in. It should be:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE user SET loggedin = 'yes' WHERE id = {$_SESSION['id']};");
```

Comment: Does it get an error? What does `echo mysqli_error($con);` show?

Comment: can i do the same and change loggedin to no when the user logs out?

Comment: should i use if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) and then update it to no ?

Comment: Yes, that `if` will confirm that they're actually logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
UPDATE user SET loggedin = 'yes' WHERE userid = 1;
```

To this:

```
mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE user SET loggedin = 'yes' WHERE userid = 1');
```

Please don't use the `md5()` function hashing passwords, it isn't safe, use these functions instead:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

You also use this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
```

To check if the username exists, I suggest changing it to this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query))
```

It does the same but you need less code to do it.

Other than that, please also learn how to `prepare` your queries before inserting them, your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection, more about that can be found here:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)